# Error creating a Python Flask project with Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a project in a Container on Docker with Dockerfile and Compose but i'm getting an error when i'm trying to `docker-compose up`

[image]

Here is my files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Compose

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
```

Tried to run `docker-compose build` and after `docker-compose up` and access on my localhost:/5000 but didnt work.

Comment: You seem to have included an image in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?  ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Answer (score -1):

Well, i was rewriting the code and found that i made the 'volume' on compose.yml part wrong, the correct is
    `volumes: - ./app`

I'm just wondering now why the server is running on 3 ips:
[image]

Comment: The correct fix is probably to delete the `volumes:` block entirely; you `COPY` the code into the image and you don't need to overwrite it with a volume mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze Done and worked, thanks! (just starting in Docker ;) )